# Radiative corrections for the vacuum polarization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

In Vanderhaeghen et al. (Phys. Rev. C 62 025501), the photon propagator modified by the vacuum polarization is
$$ 
\Pi(Q^2) = \frac{-e^2}{(4\pi)^2} \frac{4}{3}
\left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon_{UV}} -\gamma_E + \ln(\frac{4\pi \mu^2}{m^2}) -(v^2- \frac{8}{3})
+v \frac{(v^2-3)}{2} \ln(\frac{v+1}{v-1})
\right]
$$
and $$ v^2 \equiv 1+ \frac{4m^2}{Q^2}.$$

The normalization is carried out using the following relation:
$$
\tilde{\Pi}(Q^2) = \Pi(Q^2) -\Pi(Q^2=0).$$

In the end, the normalized propagator is
$$ 
\tilde \Pi(Q^2) = \frac{\alpha}{3\pi}
\left[(v^2- \frac{8}{3})
+v \frac{(3-v^2)}{2} \ln(\frac{v+1}{v-1})
\right].
$$

I don't understand how the normalized propagator is obtained given that v tends to $\infty$ when $Q^2$ tends to 0. How do you take care of the $v^2$ term when $Q^2$ tends to 0?